# How to reload repmgr configuration changes?

Tags: repmgr

I use repmgr to provide failover to my PostgreSQL cluster.
If I change a server-specific parameter in the repmgr.conf file for one of my standbys, how do I get repmgr to recognize the changed value?  For example, if I wanted to change the priority of one of the nodes.

I tried stopping & retarting repmgrd on the affected server.
Then I tried unregistering the server from the cluster & re-registering the node.
I tried registering the node with the force option.
I tried stopping repmgrd for all my servers & then stopping & restarting PostgreSQL on the Primary & then restarting the repmgrd for all the servers.
Nothing works - the cluster show command still shows the old value.

I've searched on the internet, but I can't find any information on how to reload the repmgr configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, Karin

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when I change the values in `repmgr` database (`nodes` table), it is instantly reflected when running `cluster show` command.

In my case, I wanted to change the priority of servers and modify the value in the config, restarting the service didn't do the trick.

Sadly, I have no idea why unregistering and registering didn't have the same effect in your scenario, as it should delete and insert the record in the mentioned `nodes` table.